# Rails form_for multiple different class objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to have multiple and different models in one form_for in rails 4?

maybe something like

```
# gives error
<%= form_for ([@user, @pet]), url: some_path do |u, p| %>
```

Comment: What are your routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with `form_for` helper because it takes only one record. Syntax with `[@user, @pet]` is for building right routes for associated records. Only last element of passed array will be used as record. Other will be used to create right routes. So, in your example, assuming user has one or many pets and `@user` is persisted, result route will look like one of the following:

```
"user/#{@user[:id]}/pet/#{@pet[:id]}" # when @pet is persisted
"user/#{@user[:id]}/pet/new" # if @pet = Pet.new
```

You can define your own helper and form builder or just write custom template view to accept multiple records.

Answer (score 3):

Typically something like this is done with associations of the two models. In which case, I will take a few assumptions here. I assume that you have two models `user` and `pet`. I assume that a `pet` belongs to a `user` and a `user` can have many `pets`. With this kind of association, a `pet` model would have a `user_id` attribute that would association the user to that pet.

**User Model**

```
attr_accessible :name, :pets_attributes
has_many :pets
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pets
```

**Pet Model**

```
attr_accesible :user_id, :name
belongs_to :user
```

Personally, I am a big fan of using `simple_form` as it has a cool association feature.

**View**

```
<% simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :pets do |p| %>
    <% p.input :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

Within your controller, (going to assume that this is a `new` action). This will create a line for the user and build three spots for the pets.

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  3.times do
    @user.pets.build
  end
end
```

**Routes**

One thing that you may want to consider with the routes is to set them up similar to this. This would create your routes to be a bit prettier as a Pet show action would also be referenced to the user `/users/:user_id/pets/:pet_id`

```
resources :users do
  resources :pets
end
```